# Stored Procedure - issues with query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I'm simply unable to to find a solution for this stored procedure query.

I have `Person` and a `Student` table. In `Person` table I store a bool value `isFootballPlayer` and `Student` table has an FK `PersonId` that links it to the `Person` table.

I have a web app where there is a search functionality that includes checkbox for Student, Person, and Football Player, in order to filter the results. So when only Person is selected, it will return all which are **not** Players nor Students.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
"SP stuff"
@IncludePerson bit,
@IncludePlayer bit,
@IncludeStudent bit
AS
BEGIN
    WITH i (Id)
    SELECT 
        p.PersonId as Id
    FROM 
        Person p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Student s ON s.PersonId = p.PersonId
    WHERE
        (s.PersonId IS NULL OR @IncludeStudent = 1) AND
        (p.IsFootballPlayer = 0 OR @IncludePlayer = 1) AND
        ((s.PersonId > 0) OR @IncludePerson = 1)
    )
    SELECT i.Id
    FROM i
    GROUP BY i.Id
END
```

The issue here is that some of the students can also be football players, and so when only the student checkbox is checked, the result excludes the students that are also football players, unless both checkboxes are checked.

Can anyone help me in the right direction and give me some tip on how I can modify the stored procedure to manage to show students that are also football players, without having to check both checkboxes?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what do you want to return on each combinations of check boxes checked ? it a unclear what do you expect when only footballer is checked or when the person checkbox is not checked at all. or when more than one check box is checked like students and footballers.

Comment: Sorry for not being very accurate. Well what I expect is that when only one checkbox is selected, then the result will only be either footballer, person or student! If all are selected, that would naturally return everyone. When f.ex person and student are selected, then I want the footballers to be left out, and the same would be for any other combination; that the unchecked would not end up in the result! As far as I can understand, your query would work, only when on of the checkbox is selected!

Answer (score 0):

```
"SP stuff"
@IncludePerson bit,
@IncludePlayer bit,
@IncludeStudent bit
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT DISTINCT p.PersonId as Id 
            FROM  Person p
            WHERE 1 = 1 '

          -- When only Person checkbox is checked  
          + CASE WHEN (@IncludePerson = 1 AND @IncludeStudent = 0 AND @IncludePlayer = 0)
          THEN N' AND p.IsFootballPlayer = 0  
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Student s
                                  WHERE s.PersonId = p.PersonId)' ELSE N'' END
          -- When only Student checkbox is checked  
          + CASE WHEN (@IncludePerson = 0 AND @IncludeStudent = 1 AND @IncludePlayer = 0)
          THEN N' AND  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Student s
                               WHERE s.PersonId = p.PersonId)' ELSE N'' END
          -- When only Player checkbox is checked  
          + CASE WHEN (@IncludePerson = 0 AND @IncludeStudent = 0 AND @IncludePlayer = 1)
          THEN N' AND p.IsFootballPlayer = 1 ' ELSE N'' END
          -- And you can add as many as combinations you want 

-- Finally execute the dynamically built sql query 

  Exec sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

Comment: Sorry for not being very accurate. Well what I expect is that when only one checkbox is selected, then the result will only be either footballer, person or student! If all are selected, that would naturally return everyone. When f.ex person and student are selected, then I want the footballers to be left out, and the same would be for any other combination; that the unchecked would not end up in the result! As far as I can understand, your query would work, only when on of the checkbox is selected!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the variable @IncludePlayervalue = 1 inside your stored procedure when @IncludeStudent  = 1 like mentioned below -

```
"SP stuff"
@IncludePerson bit,
@IncludePlayer bit,
@IncludeStudent bit
AS
BEGIN
if @IncludeStudent = 1
   begin
     set @IncludePlayer = 1
   end
    WITH i (Id)
    SELECT 
        p.PersonId as Id
    FROM 
        Person p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Student s ON s.PersonId = p.PersonId
    WHERE
        (s.PersonId IS NULL OR @IncludeStudent = 1) AND
        (p.IsFootballPlayer = 0 OR @IncludePlayer = 1) AND
        ((s.PersonId > 0) OR @IncludePerson = 1)
    )
    SELECT i.Id
    FROM i
    GROUP BY i.Id
END
```

Comment: Hello **sam** and thank you for your comment! I guess I was a bit to hasty in writing my previous comment about what kind of results I am expecting, so I really hope I manage to do it well this time. 
The case here is that since `isFootballPlayer` is part of `Person` and not an individual table like `Student`, when only one checkbox is selected(lets say players), there will naturally be _person_ or _students_ whom are also _players_. So in this case I also expect students/person, but whom are also players, to show up!